# How to kill a thread and handler before going to new activity

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

Hey all - this code might be a bit messy in the way I'm trying to clean up the handler as I've been trying to track down where the crash happens...

I've got a dialog activity that is showing a password entry with a progressbar being animated by a thread and handler...

It seems that when I'm attempting to see if the progressbar is done, and trying to kill the thread, the way I'm doing this is messing something up when I try to go to a new activity - ie in a way calling a function and not having anything to return *to* or something...

```
public class RMO_Dialog extends Activity {
    private ProgressBar progbar;
    private Button dialogOK;
    private EditText dialogPass;
    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    private String pass;
    private int increment=10;
    private Thread background;

    private Boolean commCalled=false;

    public void callCommunications(){
        progbar.setVisibility(0);
        progbar.setProgress(0);
        background.stop();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Call communication should happen once.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//      Intent i = new Intent();
//      i.setClass(RMO_Dialog.this, RMO_Comm.class);
//      i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
//      startActivity(i);
//          finish();
    }

    public void buzzUser(){

        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        int dot = 200;
        int dash = 500;
        int short_gap = 200;
        int medium_gap = 500;
        int long_gap = 1000;
        long[] pattern = {0,dot, short_gap, dot, short_gap, dot, medium_gap, dash, short_gap, dash, short_gap, dash, medium_gap, dot, short_gap, 
                dot, short_gap, dot, long_gap};

        v.vibrate(pattern, -1);


    }

    public void killCountdown(){
        progbar.setVisibility(0);
        progbar.setProgress(0);
        background.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dialogpassword);

        buzzUser();

        prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("RMO", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        pass = prefs.getString("password", "");

        dialogOK = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dialogOK);
        dialogPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dialogPass);
        progbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);

        progbar.setProgress(0);

        background = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try{
                    while(progbar.getProgress()<=progbar.getMax()){
                        Thread.sleep(300);
                        progressHandler.sendMessage(progressHandler.obtainMessage());
                    }
                }catch(java.lang.InterruptedException e){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error thrown.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }

        });
        background.start();

        dialogOK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(dialogPass.getText().toString().equals(pass.toString())){
                    killCountdown();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Guardian Angel next alert has been disengaged.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setClass(RMO_Dialog.this, RMO.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }else{
                    callCommunications();
                }
            }
        });



    }

    Handler progressHandler = new Handler(){
        public void handleMessage(Message msg){
            progbar.incrementProgressBy(increment);
            if(progbar.getProgress()==progbar.getMax()){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "commcalled: "+ commCalled, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if(commCalled==false){
                    commCalled=true;
                    callCommunications();
                }

            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I fixed your formatting a bit, don't forget to select your code and click on the *code formatting button* (101010)... you can also format your code after you submit your question by clicking **edit** below the question.

Answer (score 7):

[Thread.stop is deprecated call](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop%28%29), instead you should use the [Thread.interrupt](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29) method.

```
public void killCountdown(int waitTime){
    progbar.setVisibility(0);
    progbar.setProgress(0);
    // deprecated: background.stop();
    background.interrupt(); // <-- OK
    background.join(waitTime); // optionally wait for the thread to exit
}
```

`Thread.Interrupt` will cause a `ThreadInterruptedException` next time your thread blocks or sleeps and you're already handling in your thread body so that's good. Additionally, you might want to include a `volatile` flag that will allow you to stop the thread when it's not blocking or sleeping, but that's optional.

Comment: Nice explanation, especially for the exception that I did not handle in my Android app. You helped me to understand thanks!

Comment: @Zonata great! Also- please don't forget to accept the question that best solved your issue by clicking on the check mark to the left (just under the votes).

Comment: Lirik - I would, but it's not my question ;)

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using an **[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)** instance instead of a runnable and a handler.

If you need to cancel an AsycnTask instance just call `.cancel(true)` on your AsyncTask object reference. This will take care of both the background method (`doInBackground()`) and the progress updater (`onProgressUpdate()`).

I generally find AsyncTask easier to use than trying to handle all the details myself.

So, inside RMO_Dialog, use call `execute()` on an instance of a class you create that extends AsyncTask.

```
public class RMO_Dialog extends Activity {

    ...
    // Get ref to your bg task for easily cancellation if needed
    PassWordEntry background = new PassWordEntry();
    // Start bg task
    background.execute([PARAMS]);
    ...
    // Cancel task
    background.cancel(true);
    ...

    // AsyncTask lets you encapsulate both your runnable and handler in it
    private static class PassWordEntry() extends AsyncTask<[PARAMS], [PROGRESS], [RESULT]> {
        protected [RESULT] doInBackground() {
            ... // Runnable stuff here
            return [RESULT];
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate([PROGRESS]... progress) {
            ... // progressHandler stuff here
        }

        protected void onPostExecute([RESULT]) {           
            // Clean up return data when all done w BG here
        }
    }

}
```